# How to retrieve data from firebase to show products

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to show my products in the homepage by taking from firestore collections and show it using StreamBuilder. but what my homescreen shows is its returning 'hihihihi'. I have used the correct collection reference with the correct field name.

Your help in this case will help a beginner flutter developer to complete his university project.

Thanks

Here is my code

```
Container(
            height: 190,
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: collectionReference.snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 6),
                        itemCount: 4,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          children:
                          snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                            (e) => Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              height: 199,
                              width: 344,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                                    blurRadius: 6.0,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    child: Positioned(
                                      child: Image(
                                        image: AssetImage(
                                          'assets/item1.png',
                                        ),
                                        height: 200,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    right: 20,
                                    top: 10,
                                    child: Text(
                                      e['name'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 25,
                                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                
                                  Positioned(
                                    right: 20,
                                    bottom: 10,
                                    child: Text(
                                      e['price'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 30,
                                          fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                          return Center(child: Text('hi'));
                        });
                  }
                  return Center(child: Text('Empty'));
                }),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the itemBuilder should return how every item in the ListView will be built. Currently what you do is map the entire snapshot and then return a plan Text widget with hi in it.
Try the code below for the itemBuilder:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final e = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      height: 199,
      width: 344,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey,
            offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
            blurRadius: 6.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Positioned(
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/item1.png',
                ),
                height: 200,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 20,
            top: 10,
            child: Text(
              e['name'],
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        
          Positioned(
            right: 20,
            bottom: 10,
            child: Text(
              e['price'],
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

Also keep in mind that your itemCount is 4 and you probably want is to be:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Brother, i was suffering so much to do this. Means alot